# How can I get Google Fusion Tables to work in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, ogr, google-fusion-tables

I am using GDAL/OGR 1.10 and QGIS 2.0.1.

I am trying to load a google fusion table into QGIS using the method mentioned in [this blog post](http://www.webrian.ch/2011/09/google-fusion-tables-in-qgis.html). The only difference is that I am not declaring a email and password but using the OAuth refresh token I have generated. My VRT code is shown below.

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="ps">
       <SrcDataSource>GFT:refresh=<MY_VERY_LONG_TOKEN_IN_HERE> tables=1kQSkw-2cM_PU_jnu_T_PIksBkbyXm1feYaIooq8</SrcDataSource>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

But if I then add this layer to QGIS I get an OGR error that said "OGR[3] error 1: HTTP error code : 400", followed by another "OGR[3] error 1: Fetching OAuth2 access code from auth code failed."

I thought that this would have worked because via the commandline I can use OGR to open the data source as shown in the image below.

[image]

I have also tried structuring my VRT layer like in the blog post also with no luck. I'm a bit stuck on how to make this work. Any suggestions?

Thanks
Ando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I can't test it, your VRT is different to that specified here: http://www.webrian.ch/2011/09/google-fusion-tables-in-qgis.html

Try this:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="ps">
       <SrcDataSource>GFT:refresh=<MY_VERY_LONG_TOKEN_IN_HERE></SrcDataSource>
       <SrcLayer>1kQSkw-2cM_PU_jnu_T_PIksBkbyXm1feYaIooq8</SrcLayer>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Comment: Champion - nice pickup

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Works fine. I can add the layer add features, change attributes and the table reflects the changes. Sometimes it's a tad slow but I don't think that's related to QGIS or OGR. Maybe network speed or read/write speed to the GFT.